# Make a JS function with setInterval block until timer disappears

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval

I have the following function written as part of a game simulation:

```
function initialize() {
    setMaxAgents($('#maxAgents').val());
    initCanvas();
    initSwarm();
    renderSwarm();

    date = new Date();
    overallStartTime = date.getTime();

    frames = 0;

        timerID = window.setInterval(doFrame, 25);
}
```

The timer is cleared once it has nothing to render any more. I would like to be able to run this function `n` times, like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        initialize();
    }
```

However, as far as `initialize()` is concerned it returns as soon as the timer is set, so running it 10 times just ends with only the last iteration being run to completion.

How do I make `initialize()` block until the timer runs its course, so that I can run the function `n` times consecutively?

EDIT:

Here is the doFrame() code. When a condition is met it stops the timer.

```
function doFrame() {
    date = new Date();
    startTime = date.getTime();

    moveSwarm();
    renderSwarm();

    if (numAgents == 0) {
        window.clearTimeout(timerID);

        //Calculate average frames per second
        date = new Date();
        var elapsedTime = (date.getTime() - overallStartTime) / 1000;
        frameRate = frames / elapsedTime;
    } else if (frames % 5 == 0) {
        calculateFramerate();
    }

    showFramerate();

    frames++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run `initialize` 10 times in a row?  Seems like that would only need to be called once or when you want to reset everything (for example, why initialize a canvas 10 times?)  How about restructuring your code a bit so that initialize only has to run once and call `setInterval` on `doFrame` at the end?  Maybe I am just missing the point...

Comment: We would need to see the code that eventually stops your interval timer.  It's in that code that you would call initialize() again to start things over.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll update with the doFrame() code in a bit. THe reason for this is I am doing some profiling of the code to test my render engine - I calculate the average FPS of 1 run of the code. I'd like to be able to calculate that over `n` runs just so I can test optimizations and whatnot - I was hoping there'd be a simple way I could do it without messing with the nuts and bolts of my engine too much.

Comment: The code just has a group of agents that swarm around for a bit, and when they leave the page the renderer stops. They are randomly initialized and placed so I'd like to run it multiple times to get a better idea of average performance.

Answer (score 0):

`initialize()` needs to be recursively called, and you need `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`:

```
function initialize(n) {
    setMaxAgents($('#maxAgents').val());
    initCanvas();
    initSwarm();
    renderSwarm();

    date = new Date();
    overallStartTime = date.getTime();

    frames = 0;

    if (n > 0) {
        timerID = window.setTimeout(function () {
            doFrame();
            initialize(n--);
        }, 25);
    }
}
```

Call `initialize()` with an argument of however many times you want it to run.